# Slow performance on render multiple Select tag on Google Chrome on Android

Tags: android, mobile-chrome

It's terrible slow to render an **`<select>`** element on Google Chrome on Android 6 (haven't tried on Android 5.x).
I have tried on Mozilla Firefox on Android and Chrome on iOS and both works well.
I couldn't figure it out the reason.
Has someone any clue?

Here is an exemple to reproduce the issue:

```
    <select name="test" multiple="">
        <optgroup label="group1">
            <option value="1">content1</option>
            <option value="2">content2</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="group2">
            <option value="3">content3</option>
            <option value="4">content4</option>
            <option value="5">content4</option>
            <option value="6">content4</option>
            <option value="7">content4</option>
            <option value="8">content4</option>
            <option value="9">content4</option>
            <option value="10">content10</option>
            <option value="11">content10</option>
            <option value="12">content10</option>
            <option value="13">content10</option>
            <option value="14">content10</option>
            <option value="15">content10</option>
            <option value="16">content10</option>
            <option value="17">content10</option>
            <option value="18">content10</option>
            <option value="19">content10</option>
            <option value="20">content10</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
```